# ibtool failed with exception: Some Object IDs were duplicated

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, scintilla, ibtool

I just downloaded Scintilla and thought I'd first compile and run the test project, to see it for myself. Everything compiled alright, so that was a relief, but then XCode hit me with `ibtool failed with exception: Some Object IDs were duplicated`.
I am using XCode 3.2.5. I have no idea what is relevant (except for the xib files, but I can't upload those, because SO can't display them), so please leave in the comments what is relevant to troubleshoot the issue. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Somehow, in the menu bar there were some duplicate IDs. The problem disappeared after I deleted all menus except the menu in bold from the menu bar. It's a bug in their test project.

If someone knows a way to find such a duplicate ID, I would be very grateful, because sometimes deleting so many objects isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Under build settings check "Other interface builder flag" settings. Change that to none settings and check once.

This might help in resolving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It didn't help though.